# Form submitting with 'save and new document' button

Tags: atk4

I am using a simple form to submit some new document info, and would like the user to be able to hit a 'save and new document' button so he can easily add multiple documents.
I've tried to add a button to the form which works the first time I hit the 'save&new' button, and pops up another form over the existing one, but after that the button stops working.
possibly because I haven't properly closed the previous one, when spawning the new one?

how would I do that?
I'v tried using closeDialog() before calling the new dialogURL() but that obviously does not work...

(simplified) code sample follows:

```
class page_informa_documento extends Page {

  function init(){
  parent::init();
  $f=$this->add('Form');
  $f->setModel('Document');
  $f->addSubmit('Save');
  $f->addButton('Save and new document')->js('click',$f->js()->atk4_form('submitForm','otro'));


  if($f->isSubmitted() )
  {
      // save document info we just got here
      $doc->save();

    if ($f->isClicked('otro')) 

      $f->js()->univ()->dialogURL('New Document',$this->api->getDestinationURL('/informa/documento'))->execute();

    else  $f->js()->univ()->closeDialog()->execute();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need form data, you must add multiple Submit buttons.

```
$a=$f->addSubmit('Save');
$b=$f->addSubmit('Save and Add More');
if($f->isSubmitted()){

    // save your document here

    if($f->isClicked($a)){
        $this->js()->univ()->location($this->api->url('index'))->execute();
        // go to index page, we are done
    }
    if($f->isClicked($b)){
        $this->js()->univ()->location($this->api->url()->execute();
        // stay on the same page, just reload
    }
}
```

Here is a demo: http://test-suite.agiletoolkit.org/?page=form

Source is taken from here: https://github.com/atk4/atk4-testsuite/blob/master/page/form.php#L16

Comment: thanks, I realized yesterday I was complicating things too much: just 'refreshing' the form would work, which is basically what I'm doing now...